# Where could I ask about a friend's unrequited love/depression?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about a teenager friend who is greatly affected by the feelings of love he bears for a girl. She doesn't feel the same and this upsets him.

You may say that this is a common story and he will most likely get over this, but that's not true. This thing has been present in his life for 6 years. And the worrying part is that this entire situation has taken a toll on his health, too. He constantly complains that he feels pain in different regions of the body. He received treatment for ill kidneys. Continuing on this, he is always sad and can't do his student work. His parents seem to be neglecting him. A doctor told me that if he continues like this, he can receive serious mental damage, like schizophrenia. I am his friend and I want to help him, but I don't know how. He has to forget that girl and carry on with his life. I spoke to him many times about this, but it doesn't work.

What can I do to end this? How can I help him?

That is the body of the question I would like to submit, but, however, I don't know which site can help me with this. On which site should I ask this question?

Comment: Sounds like it fits "If your question is requesting personal medical advice, it is off-topic [on Health.SE] and instead should be directed to your personal physician." Ask on their meta to be sure, but that's what I'd expect.

Comment: I thought so too,thanks @Nathan,I'll give it a try.

Comment: [Alternatively](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-over-a-friend-whom-Ive-had-unrequited-love-for), [use](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-deal-with-unrequited-love) [our](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-over-a-friend-whom-Ive-had-unrequited-love-for) [evil](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-continue-being-friends-with-my-unrequited-love-and-make-sure-that-I-dont-fall-for-her-again) [twin](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-deal-with-unrequited-love-between-me-and-my-friends).

Comment: @Nathan I was told Health isn't a good choice.I don't have any idea where to post it.

Comment: @DanielTork: Given that, I'd expect there *is* no SE site that will handle it well. Not all questions work well here. Try Quora, some random forum, or just bite the bullet and talk to an actual doctor.